# How to divide slices of pie chart based on condition in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, pie-chart

I have dataset like below:

```
A 20
B 30
C 45
D 15
E 05
```

Now I want to display them in pie chart in such a way:
Value <= 20 will be one slice (i.e. 3 in our case) and values >20 will be other slice of pie chart(i.e 2 in our example).
So pie chart will have two slices :

1. Display Count(number of values) <= 20
2. Display Count(number of values) > 20.

Can someone please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do most of the work in the report's dataset.

```
/*Creating a dummy table*/

select 'A' name, 20 value into dbo.test
union 
select 'B', 30
union
select 'C', 45
union
select 'D', 15
union
select 'E', 05

/*Report data set query*/

select '<=20' Bracket,(select count(1) from dbo.test where value <=20) cnt
union
select '>20',(select count(1) from dbo.test where value >20)
```

In the rdl, drop the `Bracket` on `Category` axis and `sum(cnt)` on `Values`.

[image]

Your report should look like this:-

[image]